# How can property that has child object assigned accessed?

Tags: c#

There are 4 classes `A, B, A1, and B1`.
`A1` is child class of `A` and
`B1` is child class of `B`;
Class `A` has one property `B`;

How Can I properly access `B1` properties inside `A1` class?

below problem is demonstrated, and also two possible solutions.
Solution N1 has a problem that you have same object stored in two properties
Solution N2 has a problem that you have to cast it every time you need the property;

Is there any better way to do this?

Minimal code example:

```cs
public class A 
{
    public A(B foo)
    {
        this.foo = foo;
    }

    public B foo { get; set; }
}

public class B {}

public class A1 : A
{
    // way N1 to do it.
    public B1 b1_foo { get; set; }
    
    public A1(B1 foo) : base(foo)
    {
        // way N1 to work
        this.b1_foo = foo;
    }
    
    public void SomeMethod() 
    {
        // access way by N1
        var val = b1_foo.SomeProperty;
        // N2 way to access B1's SomePropery
        val = ((B1)this.foo).SomeProperty;
    }
}

public class B1 : B 
{
    public int SomeProperty {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: If you want a property of type B1 every time, why not just have the `foo` property in class A be of type B1? Or move the property `SomeProperty` from class B1 to class B?

Comment: @Ekas I dont need the properties of B1 in A class
furthermore I have A2 B2 classes children of A and B with their properties, if I move everyinthg into A and B Classes base classes would become bloated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is where we might use generics. This may help you (I hope) or it may open up a whole new world of confusion.

It looks like the only reason `A1` exists is so that it can use `B1` instead of `B`.

To make this readable I made the class names a little longer, so I'm starting with this:

```cs
public class ThingA
{
    public ThingA(ThingB foo)
    {
        this.Foo = foo;
    }

    public ThingB Foo { get; set; }
}

public class ThingB { }

public class ThingBWithExtraProperty : ThingB
{
    public int SomeProperty { get; set; }
}
```

You could create a class like this:

```cs
public class GenericThingA<T> where T : ThingB
{
    public GenericThingA(T foo)
    {
        this.Foo = foo;
    }

    public T Foo { get; set; }
}
```

The generic argument - `<T>` - means that when you create an instance of the class you'll have to specify what `T` is. And the constraint `where T : ThingB` means that whatever `T` is, it must either be `ThingB` or inherit from it.

So suppose you have an instance of `ThingBWithExtraProperty`. You could do this.

```cs
var thingB = new ThingBWithExtraProperty();
var genericThingA = new GenericThingA<ThingBWithExtraProperty>(thingB);
```

Now for this class instance, the type of `Foo` is `ThingBWithExtraProperty`. So if you want to access that property, you can call

```cs
var propertyValue = genericThingA.Foo.SomeProperty;
```

You're almost certainly already familiar with this. It's just like creating a `List<DateTime>`. The generic type is `List<T>`. `T` can be anything, but when we create a `List<DateTime>` that means all the objects in the list are `DateTime`.

---

Here's [more documentation on generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/).

And here's a [blog post of my own](https://scotthannen.org/blog/2018/04/05/the-generic-rabbit-hole-of-madness.html). The reason for the second one is that once we learn about generics, sometimes we try to solve things with them that don't make sense, and it gets really complicated. I learned that the hard way.

Comment: Thank you Scott! this makes everything much more clean, even though A1 exists for it's reason, this is still very helpful as I can have A1 inherit A, which already has generic property that A1 can use! 
And I'll try to avoid generic rabbit hole of madness :D